# How to put alphabetical index on right side of a UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 3. I would like to create a dynamic `UITableView` to hold customer names with an alphabetical index letters or tabs on the right side for quick navigation.

I have found info on how to create the dynamic `UITableView`, so I'm good there, but haven't found any info on how to the alphabetical indexing.

Could someone please provide some information on how to do the indexing on a `UITableView`?

Comment: Do not vandalize your question. Simply delete it (you can as there isn't a positive scored answer). And it's you who's the _troll_ BTW!

Answer (score 29):

There is a delegate method for UITableview to do this job.

```
override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]! { return indexTitlesArray }
```

This is the method that shows indexTitlesForTableView. return indexTitles from this method.

Here is the link for more info: [Section index titles for tableView](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/indexed-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift)

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement the delegate method `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView`. This method is used to add quick jump navigation feature with UITableView.

You can refer this article.

https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/